# Xamarin Forms: play local videos using webView (Testing Android ATM)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

Video Stored In Assets Folder(AndroidAsset)

Xaml:

```
<WebView x:Name="myWebView"  
VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
WidthRequest="500" HeightRequest="200"/>
```

Behind: PlayVideo Method Called In Page Constructor:

```
string myVideoHtml = String.Format(@"<html>
<body style='position: relative;width: 
100%;height: 0;padding-bottom: 56.25%;'>
<video poster='black.jpg' style='position: 
absolute; top: 0;left: 0;width: 100%;height: 100%;' autoplay controls>
<source src='{0}' type='video/mp4'/></video></body></html>", 
videoUrlFilename);
var html = new HtmlWebViewSource { Html = myVideoHtml};
myWebView.Source = html;
```

Tested it on android 7.0. It works like a charm but when I tested it on an android 4.2.2 IT DIDN'T WORK; Am I missing something here?

Comment: Wild shot, maybe HTML5 is not supported yet on Android 4.2.2?

Comment: Exactly what i had in mind. If so do you know another method of playing local videos on android ?

Comment: MediaPlayer -> https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using HTML5 in order to play a video file and as you stated it is working on Android 7.0 and not working on Android 4.2.2, it could be reasonable to recheck which version of Android does support HTML5 in WebView.

As an alternative you could always use old & good `MediaPlayer`:
[Official Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html)
[Official Xamarin Documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Media.MediaPlayer/)

Comment: Thanks, This is much better than what I attempted above. I'll figure something out & see if it works.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow please take a moment to get familiar with the next topic: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your webview. Old versions not play video on html video player which embedded in webview.